# Regarding bracket and parenthesis for formula in C++

Tags: c++

I was given a formula in this format

```
Data  = [ (percentage / 15) – (var1 + var2)  / 20]  *  [ var3 +  var4];
```

If I put the above statement in, it will compile with

```
sample.cpp:131:1: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
sample.cpp:131:1: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
sample.cpp:131:1: error: stray ‘\223’ in program

sample.cpp:131:81: error: ‘(percentage/ 15)’ cannot be used as a function
```

How do I change the data statement to make the formula work in C++?

Comment: Just replace the brackets with parens.

Comment: Seriously, is this a joke? Any introductory C++ material will cover this somewhere in the first pages. SO is not a substitute for research.

Comment: doesnt work. if i replace brackets with parens

Comment: @baokychen: Type the code, rather than cut-n-paste. The `stray '\xxx'` errors usually indicate that there are non-standard caracters in the input that the compiler does not like.

Comment: You should show us what you tried and the errors you got (after replacing the `[]` with `()`.)

Comment: For the first problem (stray characters), this is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: There must be a canonical for the second problem as well (for such a basic problem, even then. It was 4 years after [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/) launched). Though admittedly it is nontrivial to find.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here:

1. You cannot use `[` and `]` for grouping expressions. Change them to `(` and `)`.
2. The minus sign you're using is actually an en-dash (unicode character U+2013) not the normal hyphen-minus character that you should be using (U+002D). The mapping from source file characters to the *basic source character set* is implementation defined and your compiler doesn't map en-dash to the minus character (like most compilers, I imagine).

The tip here: don't just copy text from a document to your code, especially when that other document *isn't* code.

Here's the correct expression:

```
Data  = ((percentage / 15) - (var1 + var2) / 20) * (var3 + var4);
```

The error you're getting shows that there are three bytes appearing that shouldn't be there. They are (in octal): `342 200 223`. In binary, that's `11100010 10000000 10010011`. A quick google search will tell you that that's the binary representation of U+2013.